# Ionic unable to add Android platform fetch Error. "npm" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I tried everything from changing computers to uninstalling and reinstalling ionic cordova.

I checked my PATH, and based on the screen below is should not be causing issues. Otherwise, npm would not return its version.

Nothing seems to do the trick for my and my Windows machine.

Please review the screen capture below and let me know if you have encountered the same issue. I did Google the issue and not one single case came close to mine.

I'm using Ionic 3.16.0 and npm 3.10.10.

[image]

Comment: try updating npm

Comment: that is a really old version of npm.  I am using `5.4.2`

Comment: @SurajRao I updated npm. I used the "npm update" command. I can only presume that 3.10.10 is the highest version I can get under my OS, which is Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: @PhilipBrack Do you believe that my OS is the issue?. What OS are you using? I'm using Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank @PhilipBrack and @SurajRao. I was unaware that the complete command for updating/upgrading to the next version of npm is the following.

```
npm install -g npm
```

The above command will solve your problems if you're facing the following error while using Ionic:

```
Error. “npm” command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH
```